# I need to hash 16 digits number for hash kook up .Which method will be best?

Tags: php

I need to hash 16 digits number for hash look up . i had used  sha256 for hash but it doesn't produce only integer and aslo i need short hash that is less than 10.Please any suggestion? Thank You

My code :

```
$string ="8415056864756021";
$hash_string =hash('sha256', $string);
```

Comment: So you want to map 10^16 numbers to 10 numbers? (Or you meant " that is less than 10 digits")

Comment: less than 10 digits. And i used it as  $hash_string =hash('sha256', $string)

Comment: Use the low order 10 digits of the result.

Answer (score 0):

An MD5 or SHA1 hash in PHP returns a hexadecimal number, so all you need to do is convert bases. PHP has a function [hexdec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) that can do this for you.And taking a substring of first 10 characters(or less than 10 characters) will solve your problem.

```
$smallnum = hexdec( substr(sha1("value"), 0, 10) );
```

or

```
$smallnum = hexdec( substr(md5("value"), 0, 10) );
```

Comment: Well, this does not fit length restriction

Comment: Probably better to use the low-order 10 digits rather than the higher order digits. And do it after you convert to decimal.

Comment: before substr it gives this result 2.9414572920418E+47.

Comment: `substr()`, applied to hash-function, will increase collision chance. So on large data sets this will not be good idea

Comment: Then what will be the appropriate method ?

Comment: You want to stick 5 eggs into a basket which only holds 2 -- you'll be increasing the amount of collisions no matter what you do. EDIT: Unless you change the allowed length or num of characters of your end goal.